# Create users server-side Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a login GET request to the server side using the Firebase cloud functions.

Is it possible to auth using firebase functions? I tried `npm i firebase` inside the functions folder, but it fails to work.

Is there an option to create users using server-side code?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Can you show some code for illustration?

Comment: I edited the question, hopefully it is better now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To create Firebase Authentication users from within Cloud Functions you use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/) for Node.js.

To install it, follow the [instructions in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_the_sdk). Mostly it's:

```
$ npm install firebase-admin --save
```

And then import it into your index.js using:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
```

To create a user follow the [instructions in this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user):

> ```
> admin.auth().createUser({
>   email: "user@example.com",
>   emailVerified: false,
>   phoneNumber: "+11234567890",
>   password: "secretPassword",
>   displayName: "John Doe",
>   photoURL: "http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png",
>   disabled: false
> })
>   .then(function(userRecord) {
>     // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
>     console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
>   })
>   .catch(function(error) {
>     console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
>   });
> ```

Comment: Can I use this for login too?

Comment: Cloud Functions normally access Firebase through the Admin SDK, so they don't need to authenticate.

Comment: Sure, but in my case, I want to create a login while using a backend system. so the user can only enter an email and password, everything else should be handled server side. I don't see an option to do that here, unfortunately.

Comment: @J.Doe you can create your own auth provider, and inject whatever logic you like including hitting your cloud functions...https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth

Comment: Don't you have to return the promise? In three places. Line 1, end of then and end of catch.